# .first() can't filter my first class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can't figure out what's wrong with my jquery, i'm trying to do a Content slider but my .first() can't filter my first class for some reason.

A sample of what im talking about

jQuery

```
 1. $('.textinside').first().addClass('active');
```

CSS

```
.active{
   display: block;
}
.textinside{
   color: blue;
   font-size: 19px;
   background-color: black;
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">

<div class="textinside">text1</div>
<div class="textinside">text2</div>
<div class="textinside">text3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What makes you think that the `first` method is the problem? I'm pretty sure it isn't. Make sure you have loaded the jQuery library and the elements have been added to DOM before executing that line.

Answer (score 1):

Swap the two classes in your CSS file. The second one overwrites the first.
So use:

```
.textinside{
   color: blue;
   font-size: 19px;
   background-color: black;
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
}

.active {
   display: block;
}
```

and it will work. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bcexLgvd/